# Change XAML of different Page Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have two pages in my Xamarin Forms App, `MainPage` and `Dashboard`. I am looking to change the name of a label on my `Dashboard` page, when I change from my `MainPage` to my Dashboard. Changing page is achieved using this function on my `MainPage`.

```
String labelText = "Hello World"; 

public async void openPage(Page page)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(page);

    }
```

How do I get my `labelText` to update a `<Label/> which I have in my`Dashboard.xaml` page?

Answer (score 1):

Use MVVM pattern as it is mostly preferred for xamarin.

In xaml for Dashboard page, assign binding for label text as follows:

In the view model declare the property as follows

```
private string _labelText="<default string to appear>";
public string LabelText
{
    get { return _labelText; }
    set
    {
        _labelText= value;
        OnPropertyChanged ();
    }
}
```

Now when you navigation to this Dashboard page, property for `LabelText` will be assigned with default value you give.

If you want to show value passed from page1 as label, pass the value on

```
pushAsync(Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2("<string to be passed>"))
```

and then assign the corresponding value to label in constructor/`OnAppearing` method/property directly.

Answer (score 0):

Like is so often the case there is more than one way to accomplish your goal. To handle this using the base Xamarin Forms classes you should look at the [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/). That said to really develop out a Xamarin Forms app, I would suggest you use an MVVM framework like [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism) which has been used for years with XAML markup.